# Can we trap a light ray in a prism (in geometric optics)?

Tags: reflection, refraction, geometric-optics

In geometric optics, light rays can enter a (finite) prism of constant refractive index, and bounce off the edges as long as the incident angle is less than the critical angle of the medium.

1. Is there *some* setup in which light stays trapped inside?
2. Is it also possible in a 2-dimensional setup?
3. Is it also possible in a 2-dimensional polygon prism? I'd like a concrete example.

Note that I'm ignoring all effects other than geometric optics. Ignoring the scattering of light inside the material.

Also, the light cannot be generated inside the material. It must come from the background material. This means that the first angle inside the material must be less than the critical angle.

Comment: I doubt about that, prism may not be suitable at all because of total triangle angle sum of 180 degrees. But... add a pair of [Porro prisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porro_prism) together to form a rectangle, with total internal reflection angle of $45^\circ$ and you may capture a light in a rectangle if there will be no energy leaks.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/208375/123208

Comment: Some of those answers mention reflection from mirrors, but most of the answers are for total internal reflection.

Comment: @PM2Ring  The top two answers use mirrors. The third one goes outside geometric optics (photons that are created inside the material). The fourth one is simply wrong: there is no incident angle of light that will generate an internal 45 degree angle. The fifth one talks about wave optics. I've edited the post to clarify the setup.

Comment: If you allow for engineering of the refractive index you can in principle make 'optical black holes', see http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.3184594 this is a bit beyond a regular prism though.

Comment: @fulis This is a wave effect. I'd like something that works for geometric optics.

Comment: @RdBasha they calculate the ray trajectories using Hamiltonian optics, you don't need any wave optics, see fig.2.

Comment: @fulis Thanks. Do you know of any solution with a constant refractive index?

Comment: A single ray can be trapped in a suitable optical geometry if we allow for irrational proportions and angles. A ray bundle can not be. It might be possible to trap an infinite number of such rays, but it's probably always going to be a set of measure zero. Just a gut feeling. I will leave it to a theorist to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

One way to think about your problem is as an optical cavity, and the sides of the prism as partially reflecting mirrors. How ever since the reflectivity of the interfaces is low, it is hard to build up a large photon population in the prism and you also have the issue that when you are in equilibrium as many photons are leaving as you are putting in.

A better way is to use total internal reflection, but then you have the issue of how do you get light into the prism. The [figure](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/229860409_Evanescent_wave_cavity_ring-down_spectroscopy_with_a_total-internal-reflection_minicavity) below shows one scheme used for a spectroscopy technique where you can couple light into and out of the hexagonal prism using other prisms.
You can certainly trap light inside the cavity for measurable lengths of time, but you still have scattering or absorption losses. In this case the squiggles at a,b,c,d are molecules on the prism surface  that would interact with the evanescent wave increasing the absorption.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this is not geometric optics.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you ignore the imperfect reflectivity of mirrors, loss of energy to heat, and scattering inside the device. I suspect there are actually many ways to do this, but one would be to:

1. Build a glass cylinder with an angled port for a laser
2. Have the light enter a cylinder at below the critical angle
3. Voila, the light will reflect until the energy is dissipated and scattering occurs.

This is, by the way, essentially how optical fiber cables work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer lacks crucial details. Do you mean an infinite cylinder? The question is about a finite prism. If you have a concrete example of how a finite cylinder  might apply, please show why.

Comment: Two people have now given you a correct answer to a fairly obvious question. Yes, finite, similar to the internal reflection in  optical fiber cables. It seems you want us to do your homework or something, and that's not what this is for.

Comment: If you mean a finite cylinder, and assuming you mean that the light enters from one of its flat faces, then in a regular optic fiber light *does* escape: from the opposite face (after all, this is what optic fibers are meant for). An obvious example is light coming perpendicularly to one of the faces. If you claim that there is such a setup in which light stays trapped, then please provide the details and proof. My question is after a prism (preferably a 2d polygon), from which light *does not* escape, and bounces indefinitely. As for the other answer, see my comment to it.